# Need to store variable in another variable as string

Tags: powershell

I Want to store value `"sqlcmd -E -S $(ESCAPE_SQUOTE(SRVR))"` as string in variable.

```
$value = @"
sqlcmd -E -S $(ESCAPE_SQUOTE(SRVR))
"@
```

But while executing it is giving below error

> **Error**: SRVR:The term 'SRVR' is not recognised as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling
> of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is
> correct and try again.

Please let me know how to store that above value as string.

Comment: You can do single quotes as well

Comment: Hi Maneesh, I think from your question it is not exactly clear what your goal is. It is either: having a string that contains a literal dollar sign in it [that would be the answer from @Judd Davey] or if you want the result of the call to ESCAPE_SQUOTE(SRVR) be part of your string. BTW The latter would be probably realized by `$(ESCAPE_SQUOTE($SRVR))` (adding dollar sign before "SRVR"). The question itself lets me think the first one is correct, but the title actually would require the second one. Anyway, you probably should improve your question by clarifying that what exactly you want here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add an escape character in front of the $. In the case of PowerShell, the escape character is `` ` ``

This is usually found on the top left hand side of your keyboard, next to the number 1. Its called the "backtick".

For Example:

`` $Value = "sqlcmd -E -S `$(ESCAPE_SQUOTE(SRVR))" ``

or in your case

```
$value = @"
sqlcmd -E -S `$(ESCAPE_SQUOTE(SRVR))
"@
```